# Android Studio list() usage

Tags: android, list

I am trying to implement some IAP in my application and I am stuck on a seemingly simple part.  This is not an IAP question, this is a question about the usage of list();

The website I am following is the one written by google: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html

On this page they are directing me to simply do this:

```
List additionalSkuList = new List();
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_APPLE);
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_BANANA);
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
   mQueryFinishedListener);
```

It's that easy!

Except it isn't. The compiler will not allow me to simply write "new List();" like that because it is abstract.   It wants me to override some stuff but there are hundreds of options.

Is there some easier way of doing this?  I am unable to find anything at all online about the proper usage of List(); perhaps because the word list is too general to narrow down.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `new ArrayList();`

Comment: @Buddy - Thanks for the reply bro.  Will this still work as a parameter to pass to this function?:    queryInventoryAsync(boolean, List, QueryInventoryFinishedListener).   It is asking for a List as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ArrayList` in this instance, because `ArrayList` is an indirect subclass of the interface `List`. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html).